# Network utility design in Android app

Tags: java, android, networking, system, utility

I am creating an Android app prototype which functions like this:

When users launch the app, they can browse through article title list. When they click one of them, the app switches to another activity, which contains the article contents and so on. Users can also post an article when they are on the article title list.

I am trying to create a utility class, let's say ServerConnect.java, to handle all the REST request and response. In the beginning, the class has 3 public static methods to send requests for different purpose.
1. requestArticleList
2. requestArticleContent
3. userSendArticle (user post a new article)
Then I find out that I cannot just call ServerConnect.requestArticleList(), as Android forbids network behavior on UI thread. So I change the ServerConnect class to `extends AsyncTask` class. And put requestArticleList() in doInBackground(), then do things like `new ConnectServer().execute()`

Well, this gives me what I what when I lauch the app and request for article list. However, my problem is, this ConnectServer class can only do requestArticleList as it is hardcoded in doInBackground `@Override
    protected String doInBackground(Location userLocation) {
        return requestArticleList(userLocation);
    }`)

Is there any ways I can handle all these 3 method as public static method in one utility class?

Thanks all for your patience for such a long story.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that putting this in one class is a good idea. If you afraid that some function will repeat in 3 different class you can put it in some base class like below.

Create abstract base class with common functions

```
public abstract class ConnectionUtils<A,B,C> extends AsyncTask<A,B,C> {
    // put common functions here
}
```

Then create 3 separate class for each request

```
public class RequestArticleList extends ConnectionUtils<Location, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Location... userLocation) {
        return requestArticleList(userLocation);
    }
}
```

If you really want all this functionality in one class you can create callback interface

```
public interface Callback<ResultType> {
    void onResult(ResultType result);
}
```

and then in each function create new Thread

```
public void requestArticleList(final Callback<MyResult> callback) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // your code
            callback.onResult(result);
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Drawback is that its require [switching to main thread](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#WorkerThreads) before ui update.

Comment: In my system, requestArticleList and requestArticleContent perform pretty much the same things, except the previous one sends user's location and the latter one send article id. that's the reason I don't want to create another class just for requestArticleContent method. Any suggestions?

Comment: You shouldn't be afraid to create new class for each task. Smaller class is easier to read and maintain. But if you not convinced then use thread method from above.

Answer (score -1):

```
import android.content.Context;

import android.net.ConnectivityManager;

import android.net.NetworkInfo;

public class NetworkUtil {

    public static int TYPE_WIFI = 1;
    public static int TYPE_MOBILE = 2;
    public static int TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED = 0;


    public static int getConnectivityStatus(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (null != activeNetwork) {
            if(activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)
                return TYPE_WIFI;

            if(activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)
                return TYPE_MOBILE;
        } 
        return TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED;
    }

    public static String getConnectivityStatusString(Context context) {
        int conn = NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatus(context);
        String status = null;
        if (conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_WIFI) {
            status = "true";
        } else if (conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_MOBILE) {
            status = "true";
        } else if (conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED) {
            status = "false";
        }
        return status;
    }
}
```

Comment: It will be very helpful to others if you include some explanation